# .htaccess mod_rewrite not working for friendly URL's

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have done several searches and followed tutorials, but I can't seem to get the following to work. I would like to create SEO friendly URL's using .htaccess mod_rewrite. My example will be for displaying a news story. The current url structure is this:

http://www.website.com/news/details/?newsID=40

What I would like to change it to would be this:

http://www.website.com/news/name-of-news-article/

Here is what I currently have for my .htaccess file for the rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ /news/details/?newsID=$1 [L]
```

With just this in the .htaccess file, nothing happens on the URL, it just stays how it is originally. I know the site can read the .htaccess file.

I'm guessing to get the actual article name in there, I'd have to pass a parameter containing the name, but even in the current example, nothing is happening. Any assistance would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: You'll have to handle this type of rewriting inside your application since the url stub or friendly url isn't available to apache. Furthermore, the RewriteRule you have is rewriting TO the current URL structure from something else. Read over this cheat sheet http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html

Comment: As a follow up, ^ represents the beginning of the string so you can't have it inside the []. You are trying to match one or more instances of ^/, which would simply be the first slash after your domain. The rule is in fact working as expected, it's just not being matched so it's doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading slash from matching pattern.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/details/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/?$ /news/details/?newsID=$1 [L]
```

**Reason:** Inside `.htaccess` leading slash in a URI is not matched.

#### Read more about it: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

PS: Though keep in mind that rewritten URI will be `/news/details/?newsID=name-of-news-article`

**EDIT**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+test\.htm[?\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /hello? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I removed the slash as you suggested, but now the site errors out. If I go to either 

http://www.website.com/news/ 
(this is the default page that lists all the news articles)

or 

http://www.website.com/news/details/?newsID=40

I get a 500 Internal Server Error display

Comment: `http://www.website.com/news/` will not be impacted by above rule since it expects `[^/]+` after `/news/`

Comment: @anubhava OP is trying to rewrite FROM the numeric ID TO the friendly URL. Where is the .htaccess file getting the string from?

Comment: The above code still didn't do anyting. In fact, the /news/ page can't be found now, and the details page still displays as it was originally.

Comment: @user2762748 Is this the only code in .htaccess? If not post your complete .htaccess

Comment: And you're seeing `http://www.website.com/news/` URL failing? Are you getting 404 or any other error. Provide as much details as you can.

Comment: Correct, the www.website.com/news/ url fails with the code above with a 404 page not found, but the www.website/news/details/?newsID=40 displays, although nothing changes with the URL. I'm kind of at a loss right now as I don't fully understand what each of the elements in the RewriteRule actually do.

Comment: Just to reclarify what I am trying to accomplish:

Right now, I have www.website.com/news/ - this page displays links to all the news articles on the site. The href's of the links go to www.website.com/news/details/?newsID=10 - (the #10 being an example..it's the ID of the news story stored in the database). What I want to do, is make it so that the URL displays as www.website.com/news/news-headline-goes-here/

Comment: also, the .htaccess file is located in the root of the site (www.website.com/) ... should it be located in the (/news/) directory to make this work?

Comment: First you need to understand that rewrite rule cannot translate news ID to news title. So you will need to query your database in PHP code to translate ID to title and then call header function for that redirect to happen. **However using rewrite rules we can redirect `/news/details/?newsID=10` to `/news/10/`** Let me know if you need this and I will edit my answer.

Comment: If you could provide that, it would be appreciated. Using that, I can better understand how everything is working, and then modify it so that I get it to display the headline versus the ID

Comment: I am trying a more simple example but I cant even get that to work so Im wondering if there is a different configuration that needs to happen on the server? My example:

I created a test.htm file and put it in the root directory of www.website.com

In .htaccess I have the following code:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^hello/?$   test.htm  [NC]


If I go to www.website.com/hello I get the following error:

Not Found
The requested URL /test.htm was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2 Server at www.website.com Port 80

If I actually go to http://www.website.com/test.htm - the file loads.

Comment: That is really weird, try: `RewriteRule ^hello/?$ /test.htm [NC,L]` and then try to visit `http://www.website.com/hello` If that also doesn't work then make sure if .htaccess is enabled. Put same garbage text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generated 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: Ok that example worked! Now I can access www.website.com/test.htm from both that URL and www.website.com/hello. Now this brings up another question - To avoid duplicate content penalties, would I have to add something to the .htaccess file, or would I put code in the test.htm file?

Comment: That will an additional rule in .htaccess itself, see edit section above.

Comment: Could you explain what is going on in the RewriteCond

Comment: That is an external redirect which uses `THE_REQUEST` variable (which represents original request received by Apache). `RewriteCond` checks whether request is being made for `/test.htm` and then it gets redirected to `/hello`. Read docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html